# Knockout Mapping overwriting Computed Observables, is this intentional?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Say, you have a setup as below:

```
var model = function() {
    this.base = ko.observable("Initial");
    this.dependent = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.base() + ", computed";
    }, this);
};

var vm = new model();
```

At this point, `vm` is `Object { base: observable(), dependent: dependentObservable() }` (as expected)

But, once I run:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({base: "hello", dependent: "hi"}, {}, vm)
```

`vm` becomes `Object { base: observable(), dependent: "hi", __ko_mapping__: Object }`

`dependent` is no longer an observable, I was expecting it to be untouched.

Is this intentional? If so, what is the rationale behind this? Shouldn't dependent observables be kept out of mapping?

---

The reason for this question is that, I am using ko.mapping.toJS() to convert `vm` to a JavaScript `object` (which gives a `dependent` property, as expected).

Then, sometime later, I'm using ko.mapping.fromJS() as shown above. This combination overwrites `vm`'s ko.computed() property.

---

Solutions I could come up with:

- Explicitly specify `dependent` to be ignored during mapping.

  ```
  ko.mapping.fromJS({base: "hello", dependent: "hi"}, {'ignore': "dependent"]}, vm)
  ```
- Make `dependent` writable (just for namesake)

  ```
  this.dependent = ko.computed({
      read: function() {
          return this.base() + ", computed";
      },
      write: function() {},
      owner: this 
  });
  ```

---

Misc. Info

- [The Line](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/35482d03ee7520b1afe0b437a6e66150369378a7/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js#L479) which actually overwrites the dependentObservable() (as far as I can understand)

Comment: It's by design. Here is another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20534370/2326610. It uses the mapping create function to add the computed.

Comment: As @WayneEllery already mentioned that this is by design (or a missing feature). The mapping plugin only checks that the property is an writable observable then update its value. If the property is not a writable observable it just completely override the property with the new value (this happens with your non writable computed). So the proper solution for this to ignore your computed properties in the config.

Comment: @nemesv: That's a great point, thanks a lot! I think we've got the reason why it's behaving as it is. Do you have any link(s) to some documentation that defines this behavior (or do we just [RTFS](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/))? I ask because the [current documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) states that "All properties of an object are converted into an observable." under "How things are mapped".

Comment: Working with knockout for 4 years and I would never use ko.mapping. It’s really bloated and almost never gets results. Fastest way for is to implement a function which will take JS obkect and return Model with bindings.